# Function passed via a prop to child component is not a function when called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem when I pass a function from a parent component to a child component via its props and call that function I get an error saying "your function is not a function".

This is the child component:

```
const AppointmentItem = (props) => {
  const { authRole, data, chosenItem } = props;

  ...

  <Button
    onClick={() => chosenItem(card.cardId, 'rejected')} // error is not function  
  >

  ...
}
```

This is the parent component:

```
const chosenItem = (id, type) => {
  setSelectedItem(id);
  if (type === 'accepted') operation(id, 'accepted');
  if (type === 'rejected') setRejectForm(true);
};

...

<AppointmentItem
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  key={index}
  data={card}
  chosenItem={chosenItem}
  authRole={authRole}
  operation={operation}
/>
```

When `chosenItem` is called in the child component I get an error saying `chosenItem` is not a function.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code, the problem is somewhere else. A [Mcve] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use proptypes checker to check is function pass as function or not and you should set it to "proptypes.function" and then use proptypes.defaultProps and pass it a null as example --:

```
classname.defaultProps:{myFunction:null}

className.propType:{

myfunction:proptype.function
}
```

the answer is remove isrequired and use defalutProps

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine, the problem is either with `setSelectedItem`, `operation` or `setRejectForm`.

I suggest you put a `debugger;` statement or a regular breakpoint in chosenItem and inspect each of the functions I mentioned above and see which one is undefined.

If you would like more help/details please upload a reproducible example to [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: i define another function that return console.log and passed into child component but again it's tell me x is not function

Comment: Can you upload a reproducible example to code sandbox or share the full code of your components? I don't have enough info to help you

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by your child component being the child of more than one component. I also faced this error, in my case my child component is child to two components and when I remove my child component from one parent, then my error is resolved. I hope this also work in your case.